# Qt widgetAt returns unexpected pointer when window is minimized

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I need to check whether a QWidget exists in (x,y)

I use the following code:

```
QWidget *pObject = QApplication::widgetAt(mapToGlobal(QPoint(x, y)));
```

It works correctly when the window is normal; but when the window is minimized, it returns a wrong value...

How can I get correct value when the window is minimized?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question but when it is minimized you won't see it on the global map, right? so this would not work

Comment: Yes, you're right.  
  
In fact, i am writing a game like NS-SHAFT.  
I wanna use widgetAt to check the human whether stand on a stair.  
  
The following is my steps:  
1. Obtain QWidget in (human.pos().x(), human.pos().y() + human.height())  
2. If there is a stair, human stand on it

Comment: In Qt Assistant, widgetAt says "Returns the widget at [ global ] screen position point, ..."  
In other words, does it exist a way to obtain QWidget in window map rather than global map?  
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sorry I don't really know about those positions. But you can look at the functions from the qwidget class. Maybe there's a function you can use : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html

Comment: Thanks @Davlog for reply :)
You're right. The best solution is in QWidget member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `widgetAt()` uses screen coordinates but in-fact your point doesn't lie on the screen when your application is minimized.

What you want is a mapping between the container widget and its content (child widget). This is provided by the `childAt()` function.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#childAt